# How to change just the distance between ticks?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can use scale_x_continuous(breaks=...) to manually set the ticks. But I don't manually set the limits but just want to change the distance between ticks. Is there a way to do so? Thanks.

```
qplot(tab[ , 1], binwidth = binwidth) + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 100, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scales::pretty_breaks` (a wrapper for base R's `pretty`) to easily specify the number of ticks you want. Given the number of ticks, `pretty_breaks` will try to choose breaks that look nice.

```r
qplot(tab[, 1], binwidth=binwidth) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=scales::pretty_breaks(n = 5))
```

The smaller you set `n`, the more distance you'll have between ticks.